# About HTML5 web worker using in 1 single js file

Tags: javascript, html, worker

The Worker must reference a `.js` file.

If a Javascript project need to export 1 single `.js` file, and this project needs to use Worker for process.

So the project has to handle `code in sub process` and `code in main process` together.

Is it possible to handle this problem, to make code looks elegant in 1 single `.js` file when using Worker?

Comment: The Question you pasted is about "How to code worker in a single file", my question is how to code it elegantly.

Comment: Ah. Your question is unclear then.

Comment: Define "elegant", or at least give examples of what you consider "non-elegant".